# php soap proxy failing in web service action call

Tags: php, soap, proxy

I am making a webservice call using proxy. 
The SoapClient call which uses proxy works fine but the call to webservice function using the same SoapClient object is failing. When i asked the server people, they said they can see the first GET call but not the POST call.

Here is the code:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
array(
    'ssl' => array( 'SNI_enabled' => false, 'SNI_server_name' => $domain
    ),
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'proxyurl:8080'
    )
)
);

$soapOptions = array(
    'trace' => true,
    'stream_context' => $context
);


try {
    $client = new SoapClient(WSDL_URL, $soapOptions);
}  catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {".$fault->faultcode."}, faultstring: {".$fault->faultstring."})", E_USER_ERROR;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "SOAP Exception: (faultcode: {".$fault->faultcode."}, faultstring: {".$fault->faultstring."})", E_USER_ERROR;
}

echo "Calling Grant Role";
echo "<hr>";

$userName = "username";
$roleIdFromUser = "userrole";

try {
    $result = $client->GrantAffiliateUserRole(array('affiliateId' => AFFILIATEID, 'password' => AFFILIATEPASSWORD, 'username' => $userName, 'roleId' => $roleIdFromUser));
    echo "Success";
}  catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "SOAP Proxy Fault: (faultcode: {".$fault->faultcode."}, faultstring: {".$fault->faultstring."})", E_USER_ERROR;
    echo "Failed Grant Fault";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "SOAP Exception: (faultcode: {".$fault->faultcode."}, faultstring: {".$fault->faultstring."})", E_USER_ERROR;
    echo "Failed Grant Exception";
}
```

The output is:

```
object(SoapClient)#1 (4) { ["trace"]=> int(1) ["_stream_context"]=> resource(2) of type (stream-context) ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(4) of type (Unknown) } 

Calling Grant Role

SOAP Proxy Fault: (faultcode: {HTTP}, faultstring: {Could not connect to host})256

Failed Grant Fault
```

Again, the webservice action call is not recognizing proxy that was used to make SoapClient call for WSDL.Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have got this solved. Since the Web service URL is HTTPS, just the SSL needs to be stream context and pass it along with the Proxy array to the WSDL call as below.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
array(
    'ssl' => array('SNI_enabled' => false)
    )
);

$soapOptions = array('proxy_host' => PROXY_HOST, 'proxy_port' => PROXY_PORT, 'stream_context' => $context);

$client = new SoapClient(WSDL_URL, $soapOptions);
```